# r graphic output window is tiny and cannot correctly be maximized

Tags: r, plot, font-size

I wanted to plot data with R but the graphic output window opens, it is too small. When I maximize the window, the plot is maximized, however the fonts stay as tiny as they were.

What can I do about this?

I am running Debian with xfce4 desktop, if that is important.

Comment: I prefer to output to a "reliable" device, like `png` or `pdf`, where I can control the `width` and `height` of the figure.

Comment: For viewing in the output window, you could try increasing the font sizes. For example, in base graphics, use the `cex` family of graphics parameters: `plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis", main="Plot Title", cex.axis=2, cex.main=2, cex.lab=2)`.

Comment: So this is not a bug? I also output to pdf normally, but to quickly compare different parameters I thought a direct plotting was useful.

Comment: By the way: The cex helped to get this better, thanks!